# How to match terms except those after specific word using spacy matcher?

Tags: python, regex, spacy, text-mining

I have multiple research papers containing the terms: "social media platform" and "media platform".

I want to match all "media platform" terms without touching the "social media platform" terms.

Here is my example text:

"The social media platform is great. It is a great media platform."

I just want to match "media platform in the second sentence leaving out the one in the first:

"The social media platform is great. it is a great **media platform**."

The pattern I use so far is not quite working because it also matches the word "great"..

"The social media platform is great. it is a **great media platform**."

Here is my pattern:

```html
pattern = [{'LOWER': 'social', 'OP': '!'},
           {'LOWER': 'media'},
           {'LOWER': 'platform'}]
```

Is it even possible to solve this task with spacy matcher? Or is there a possibility to use regex?

Comment: If you need a regex solution, what was the regex you tried? What did not work?

Comment: I use spacy matcher because it is more intuitive. But for these a little more complex tasks i don´t know if spacy matcher works. Unfortunatly I am a beginner and dont know how to create more complex regex patterns like these..

Comment: Regex is easy here, it is a commonly used negative lookbehind - `r'(?<!\bgreat\s)\bmedia platform\b'`

Comment: How can I include this regex into my Spacy matcher? I know that there is a possibility to use regex in spacy matcher..  it is important for my workflow

Comment: I don't think there is a way.

Comment: is it then possible to use a negative lookbehind with spacy matcher?

Comment: No, it is not possible. Regex matches plain text only. In the matcher patterns, you can use regex to match a single token only.

Comment: Doesn't the pattern example in the question match what you want with the Matcher, though? The only match it would miss is one at the very beginning of a text `media platform is...`.

Comment: no, I want all "media platform" terms, except those that are contained in "social media platform". Because I want to think of "social media platform" and "media platform" as two different concepts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get exactly what you want with the spaCy matcher because of the way the negation op works. You should just use a function to filter matches, something like this:

```
matches = ... matcher output ...
final = [mm for mm in matches if mm.start == 0 or mm.doc[mm.start-1].text != "social"]
```

There is no reason to use regex for this problem.

Comment: yes, that is a good workaround! Thank you!